# cannot find correct iwlwifi-8265 version

Tags: debian, iwlwifi

I have a Thinkpad L380 with Intel 8265, on which I installed Debian 9 base system (from a netinstall USB stick). I downloaded https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz, which had the file iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode, which I copied to /lib/firmware and rebooted the machine.

The output of 
`dmesg | grep iwlfifi`
has the following lines. (There might be some typos, since Ihad to read it from the laptop and type it here, since iwlwifi isn't working on it, and I can't connect it to ethernet for want of a mini-RJ45 connector!)

```
firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8265-26.ucode (-2)
Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-26.ucode failed with error -2
```

Similarly for -25, -24 and -23. Then

```
firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode
loaded firmware version 22.361476.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265 REV=0x230
L1 enabled - LTR enabled
L1 enabled - LTR enabled
wlp2s0 renamed frm wlan0
```

Looking at many online discussions/blogs discussing similar problems, I tried `modinfo iwlwifi | more` which gave (the first few line)

```
filename: /lib/modules/4.9.0-8-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
licence: GPL
author : ....
descrption: Intel(R) Wireless Wifi driver for Linux
...
...
firmware: iwlwifi-8265-26.ucode
...
```

Where can I find version -26 (or anything above -22)? The discussion https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P0000490P1ASAU/iwlwifi8265-linux-firmware?language=en_US mentions that the drivers are maintained at kernel.org and asks users to contact the support people at kernel.org, but there I could only find -22.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not answering the above question, but here is what I leant to solve a similar problem in a different Lenovo laptop with Intel 3165 wireless card. It has the same firmware as the 7265 (https://www.intel.in/content/www/in/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html).

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i iwlwifi
[    8.915617] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode (-2)
[    8.915624] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.915667] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode (-2)
[    8.915673] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.915707] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode (-2)
[    8.915713] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.915746] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode (-2)
[    8.915752] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.369135] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
[    9.369712] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.391740.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    9.920513] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
[    9.922593] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    9.922804] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   11.118178] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

I asked the Debian kernel maintainers about this issue: I could only find `iwlwifi-7265D-{27,22}.ucode` online but the driver was trying to load `iwlwifi-7265D-{26,25,24,23}.ucode`. One of them replied that versions 26--23 are not "required" and the driver has loaded version 22 successfully. (He replied about the 8265 problem mentioned my question, but I supposed it applied in this case too.) After reading some online discussions about `wicd`, I looked at its settings (Dropdown Arrow on its GUI -> Preferences -> General Settings -> Wireless interface). The field was empty. I suspect that this had to do `wlan0` being renamed as `wlp2s0`. When I entered `wlp2s0` there, I was able to connect using wifi.

Comment: A strange thing is that I have two laptops running the same debian `Linux HOSTNAME 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (2018-05-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux` one with the Intel 3165 mentioned above and the other Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565. `iwlwifi` renames `wlan0` as `wlp2s0` while the driver for the other one does not! Hence `wicd` was able to see the networks in the laptop with Qualcomm.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [linux-firmware Git repository has had version -27 since early 2017](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/log/iwlwifi-8265-27.ucode), my guess is that the only place you would reliably find versions -23 .. -26 is Intel's internal archives, filed under "firmwares that failed in final testing before public release".

Intel actually develops the `iwlwifi` driver, so each driver version requests first *the latest firmware version that was known to exist at the time that driver version was sent to Linus for inclusion into the kernel*, and if that is not found, falls back to requesting older versions. Sometimes this includes versions that never see the light of day outside Intel's internal facilities.

Debian 9 was released in June 2017, so back in mid-2019 when the question was posted, it was already starting to show its age. If the original poster updated to Debian 10 when it was released in July 2019, the upgrade would have brought a newer kernel version with an updated `iwlwifi` driver that knows to request newer firmware versions, and a newer firmware package (in the non-free section of Debian, since firmware source code is not public) that would have included the version -36.

Otherwise, installing a Debian 9 backport kernel might have been another way to easily get a newer version of the `iwlwifi` driver: the presence of firmware version -36 in the `firmware-iwlwifi_20190114-1~bpo9+2_all.deb` package strongly suggests that the Debian 9 backport kernels would have been able to use firmware version `-36` for this WiFi chip.